# How to install Skype in Ubuntu Studio 16.04?

Tags: skype, ubuntu-studio

I used the following Terminal command to install Skype:
"sudo apt update && sudo apt install skype", as advised in this [tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-skype-4-3-in-ubuntu-16-04/#comment-3536974). But at the end of the installation attempt it says it was ***unable to locate the package Skype***

Any ideas?

Thanks guys,

Comment: The first item in that tutorial is about enabling Canonical Partners. Did you do that?

Comment: In addition to @GunnarHjalmarsson's wise advice, make sure you're typing `skype` in all lowercase letters. It's case-sensitive, and will not find the package **Skype** (with a capital "S") even if the package **skype** is available

Answer (score 1):

Just write it on terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

I just tested it here, it works.

Comment: In Ubuntu Studio 18.04 it would be `skypeforlinux`